# Fabric Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

There was an Hyperledger Fabric  error updating the anchor peer in the Building Your First Network document. This error is as follows.

> Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

I need your help.

Answer (score 11):

I fixed by bringing the network down (`byfn.sh down`)
and then up again (`byfn.sh up`).

Please see this link for more information:
[How to fix "FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario" in Hyperledger Fabric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52548185/how-to-fix-failed-to-execute-end-2-end-scenario-in-hyperledger-fabric)

Answer (score 1):

> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

This error is due to the certificate format mismatch, It happed to me when I used **v1.0 cryptogen tool** for certificate generation and ran the network with  **v1.1 Fabric containers**.

So, try to update the cryptogen tool from here -> http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/samples.html#binaries.

I don't know what version you were using so, I assumed it would be v1.1. So, please specify the Hyperledger Fabric version you were using.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.

I checked the version of my cryptogen tool and it was 1.1. 

Perhaps the problem was that the orderer.example.com did not run due to an error when running the docker compose.

Comment: Could you remember which was the error? I am following the tutorial and I find the same issue. ty

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems could be that you have an old version of the Hyperledger Example and you are pointing to an old version of the **Cryptogen tool**. So if you download a newer example, when you generate the crypto-config it will generate it with the old version of the **cryptogen tool**, this could make your orderer container to stop, cause can validate the certificate generated.

This is because the differents versions of the cryptogen tool generate different metadata.

My suggest is to check if the cryptogen version that you are using is the one contained in your downloaded image of your example. If you had run lot of tests, clean all the docker images and containers, that always help.

If nothing of that works, I wrote a tutorial based on the basic-network example and how to run it in multiple hosts, maybe you can take some information from there.

https://medium.com/1950labs/setup-hyperledger-fabric-in-multiple-physical-machines-d8f3710ed9b4

Please, feel free to ask, if you have doubts!

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to channel capabilities are set as true for v.1.4.0 so you should change it to **false** so that it can run for every version of the fabric.

Comment: Can you please detail your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
docker ps -a
```

to find container ID of `hyperledger orderer` and `peer images`. Then try:

```
docker rm *container_ID*
```

to remove them. After you can run `./network.sh up createChannel`.

Answer (score -1):

so for this error i tried doing `byfn.sh down` and `byfn.sh up` but after that it threw another error, which i solved by first killing all the containers, removing them, cleaning all images and volumes that already exist and restarted the tutorial. to kill and remove processes and images and cleaning my system.
https://medium.com/coinmonks

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -qa)
docker system prune -a 
docker volumes prune -a
```

delete fabric-samples directory and start from the beginning and you're ready to go.