# Channel capability V1_3 is required but not supported: Making my First Network in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Booting up a my first Hyperledger Network on OSX with.

I installed the sample files using the script

```
curl -sSL http://bitlyURLThatStackoverflow won't let me us | bash -s 1.2.1
```

The ran

```
./byfn.sh up -c mychannel -s couchdb
```

To boot up a sample network and got the error

```
  Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
```

Pulled the logs from orderer.example.com:7050 and got

```
config requires unsupported channel capabilities: Channel capability V1_3 is required but not supported: Channel capability V1_3 is required but not supported
```

Any suggestion on where to start debugging

Comment: When I changed the version to 1.2.0 it started working... any idea why 1.2.1 isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just getting started, you might want to move to [1.3.0](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/) anyway as it is now generally available.

EDIT: You should now be able to just use `1.2.1` and things should work.  I pushed a new `v1.2.1` tag for fabric-samples.  (read below for explanation).

To answer your question, the way the script works is that it assumes that both the fabric and fabric-samples repositories have tags matching the version specified for download.  It turns out that there is `1.2.1` tag for fabric-samples so if you cloned it yourself you'll end up with the default (which is `1.3.0`).  If you want to use the `1.2.1` images, then you can simply download them and then run `git checkout v1.2.0` in your clone of fabric-samples.