# Orderer capability V1_4_4 is required but not supported

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

When running hyperledger fabric sample, the orderer container gets exited within 1 sec. When logging the container I get the following error:

```
Orderer capability V1_4_4 is required but not supported
```

The image below shows that the binary, images and orderercapacities are based on version 1.4.4.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you replace the image with a plain-text description of what behavior you're seeing, and provide a [mcve] including any relevant code?

Comment: It's almost the same problem as this post "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52787139/channel-capability-v1-3-is-required-but-not-supported-making-my-first-network-i"

Comment: But the problem with mine, versions seem to be fine. Everything is 1.4.4 based.

Comment: I had to face the  similar issue when my images, binaries and fabric samples were not in sync. Please make sure once more if this is not the case for you.

Comment: @Pandit What I tried using images and binaries based on 1.4.4. I also modified the configtx.yaml, in the capabilities I said, as the image shows: V_1_4_4: true. What more can I do, did I forget something?

Comment: Can you share your orderer config file, the only things we see from this image is that you've defined the Orderer capabilities pointer, never that it's been consumed and that the structure of the file is correct

Answer (score 0):

There is no **v1_4_4** for orderer capabilities.

Only **v1_4_2** and **v1_1** are supported by Fabric v.1.4.4

refer sample configtx.yaml file

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/first-network/configtx.yaml